# Wikidata Query: find items where property exists

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I made a query that nicely outputs all Belgians with a birthday older than 1/1/1800. It works well.

```
https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=between[569,1800-1-1]%20AND%20claim[27:31]
```

But I only want items that have a picture, so where Property P18 exists. How do I do that in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a claim without `:item` if you just want to return if the property exists (see the [Wikidata Query docs](https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html)).

`between[569, 1800-1-1] AND claim[27:31] AND claim[18]`

https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=between[569,1800-1-1]%20AND%20claim[27:31]%20AND%20claim[18]

I would also recommend trying this as a [Wikidata SPARQL query](https://query.wikidata.org/#prefix%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Ftime0%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20(%20%3Ftime0%20%3E%3D%20%221800-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%20)%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP27%20wd%3AQ31%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fdummy0%20.%0A%7D) for faster results:

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P569 ?time0 .
  FILTER ( ?time0 >= "1800-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime )
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q31 .
  ?item wdt:P18 ?dummy0 .
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slaporte. I agree, SPARQL is way better to go on with this.
I fiddled with your solution and have this up till now, which works very well for me : 

`prefix wds: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/statement/>
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?item ?person ?des ?pict WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P569 ?time0 . 
  FILTER ( ?time0 >= "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime )
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q31 .
  OPTIONAL { ?item rdfs:label ?person filter (lang(?person) = "en") }
  ?item wdt:P18 ?pict .
  OPTIONAL { ?item schema:description ?des filter (lang(?des) = "en")   }

} `